# Writing an expression as divergence (vector algebra)

Tags: field-theory, vector-fields

Let $\Psi(\mathbf{r})\equiv \Psi$ is a Fermionic field operator. And there is an expression:
$$
\mathbf{\nabla} \cdot \mathbf{J_{r}} = (\nabla^2 \Psi^\dagger)(\nabla\Psi\cdot\mathbf{A}) + (\nabla \Psi^\dagger)\cdot(\nabla^2\Psi\mathbf{A})
$$
here $\mathbf{A}$ is a vector field. Is there any way to write the expression on right side as a divergence of some other expression to find value of $\mathbf{J_r}$?

Comment: Are you sure this is a correct expression? $\Psi^2=0$ for fermionic operator

Comment: Even if we find a divergence expression $\:\boldsymbol{\nabla\cdot}\mathbf R\:$ for the rhs this doesn't imply that
$\:\mathbf J_r\boldsymbol=\mathbf R\:$ but $\:\mathbf J_r\boldsymbol=\mathbf R\boldsymbol+\boldsymbol{\nabla\times} \mathbf S\:$ where 
$\:\mathbf S\:$ any arbitrary differentiable 3-vector function.

Comment: *Is there any way to write the expression on right side as a divergence ...?*
Is it enough to answer this just with "yes" or "no"?
Or are you supposed to find a concrete solution $\mathbf{J_r}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our equation is
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\nabla\cdot}\mathbf J_{\mathbf r}\boldsymbol=\left(\nabla^2 \Psi^\dagger\right)\left(\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi\boldsymbol\cdot\mathbf A\vphantom{\nabla^2 \Psi^\dagger}\right)\boldsymbol+\left(\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi^\dagger\right)\boldsymbol\cdot\left(\mathbf A\nabla^2 \Psi\right)
\tag{01}\label{01}   
\end{equation}
The right hand side $\:\texttt{RHS}\:$ is
\begin{equation}
\texttt{RHS}\boldsymbol=\underbrace{\left(\nabla^2 \Psi^\dagger\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi\boldsymbol+\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi^\dagger\nabla^2 \Psi\right)}_{\boxed{1}}\boldsymbol\cdot\mathbf A
\tag{02}\label{02}   
\end{equation}
But
\begin{equation}
\boxed{1}\boldsymbol=\left(\nabla^2 \Psi^\dagger\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi\boldsymbol+\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi^\dagger\nabla^2 \Psi\right)\boldsymbol=\left(\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi\boldsymbol\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla\vphantom{\nabla^2 \Psi^\dagger}\right)\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi^\dagger\boldsymbol+\left(\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi^\dagger\boldsymbol\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla\vphantom{\nabla^2 \Psi^\dagger}\right)\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi
\tag{03}\label{03}   
\end{equation}
Using the following vector formula
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol\nabla\left(\mathbf a\boldsymbol\cdot\mathbf b\right) \boldsymbol=
  \left(\mathbf a\boldsymbol\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla\right)\mathbf b\boldsymbol+\left(\mathbf b\boldsymbol\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla\right)\mathbf a\boldsymbol+\mathbf a\boldsymbol\times\left(\boldsymbol\nabla\boldsymbol\times\mathbf b\right)\boldsymbol+\mathbf b\boldsymbol\times\left(\boldsymbol\nabla\boldsymbol\times\mathbf a\right)  
\tag{04}\label{04}   
\end{equation}
with $\:\mathbf a\boldsymbol\equiv\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi\:$ and $\:\mathbf b\boldsymbol\equiv\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi^\dagger\:$ we have
\begin{equation}
\boxed{1}\boldsymbol=\left(\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi\boldsymbol\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla\vphantom{\nabla^2 \Psi^\dagger}\right)\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi^\dagger\boldsymbol+\left(\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi^\dagger\boldsymbol\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla\vphantom{\nabla^2 \Psi^\dagger}\right)\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi\boldsymbol=\boldsymbol\nabla\left(\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi\boldsymbol\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi^\dagger\right)
\tag{05}\label{05}   
\end{equation}
since $\:\boldsymbol{\nabla\times\nabla}\Psi\boldsymbol=\boldsymbol 0\boldsymbol=\boldsymbol{\nabla\times\nabla}\Psi^\dagger\:$.

From equations \eqref{02},\eqref{05} we have
\begin{equation}
\texttt{RHS}\boldsymbol=\boldsymbol\nabla\left(\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi\boldsymbol\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi^\dagger\right)\boldsymbol\cdot\mathbf A
\tag{06}\label{06}   
\end{equation}
Using the following vector formula
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol\nabla\boldsymbol\cdot\left(\psi\mathbf a\right)
\boldsymbol=
  \mathbf a\boldsymbol\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla\psi\boldsymbol +\psi\boldsymbol\nabla\boldsymbol\cdot\mathbf a  
\tag{07}\label{07}   
\end{equation}
with $\:\mathbf a\boldsymbol\equiv\mathbf A\:$ and $\:\psi\boldsymbol\equiv\left(\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi\boldsymbol\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi^\dagger\right)\:$ we have
\begin{equation}
\texttt{RHS}\boldsymbol=\boldsymbol\nabla\boldsymbol\cdot\left[\left(\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi\boldsymbol\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi^\dagger\right)\mathbf A\right]\boldsymbol-\left(\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi\boldsymbol\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi^\dagger\right)\left(\boldsymbol\nabla\boldsymbol\cdot\mathbf A\vphantom{\nabla^2 \Psi^\dagger}\right) 
\tag{08}\label{08}   
\end{equation}
that is finally

<sup>\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:\left(\nabla^2 \Psi^\dagger\right)\left(\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi\boldsymbol\cdot\mathbf A\vphantom{\nabla^2 \Psi^\dagger}\right)\boldsymbol+\left(\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi^\dagger\right)\boldsymbol\cdot\left(\mathbf A\nabla^2 \Psi\right)\boldsymbol=\boldsymbol\nabla\boldsymbol\cdot\left[\left(\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi\boldsymbol\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi^\dagger\right)\mathbf A\right]\boldsymbol-\left(\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi\boldsymbol\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi^\dagger\right)\left(\boldsymbol\nabla\boldsymbol\cdot\mathbf A\vphantom{\nabla^2 \Psi^\dagger}\right)\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}\:\:} 
\tag{09}\label{09}   
\end{equation}</sup>

So note that this expression could be a divergence if $\:\boldsymbol\nabla\boldsymbol\cdot\mathbf A\boldsymbol=0$ (this reminds us the Coulomb gauge).  Also if $\:\left(\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi\boldsymbol\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla\Psi^\dagger\right)\boldsymbol=\texttt{constant}\:$ then this is identically zero.